# To Copy data from specific cell to another sheet using a checkbox(turn false when task is done)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Need to copy data from 2 cells and paste it on sheet2 and clear the textboxes from Sheet1
Link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RiLjepEpYhkhCTgMHxrTxSI7GWloj954C4dsq0jT11E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: _copy data from 2 cells_ — what the cells? C5 and C7? And what the textboxes you want to clear on the Sheet1?

Comment: I'm assuming you want an `onEdit(e)` that is watching the checkbox in Sheet1!D5 to copy the values from C5, C7 to last row of Sheet2!A:B?  Did I read your mind correctly?  Oh, and clear the text in C5, C7.

Comment: @TheWizEd C5 and C5 are drop down lists, how could be they cleared? Probably they can be reset to some default state like 'A' and 'A'.

Comment: @YuriKhristich you can delete the value in a drop down cell or put "" and it will display "".

Comment: @TheWizEd yep, but it removes a value only from the screen. All the values still present in the drop down list. Nevertheless your answer is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description**

To monitor if a checkbox has been clicked, (not true or false) you can use an onEdit(e) simple trigger.  When the checkbox is clicked it will momentarily display a check and then the onEdit() clears both the dropdown selections and the checkbox.

I think I have given you enough to get started.  I hope you will use the references to research other aspects of Google Spreadsheet and javascript.

**Script**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Sheet1" ) {
      if( e.range.getA1Notation() === "D5" ) {
        let range = e.range.getSheet().getRange("C5:C8")
        let values = range.getValues();
        let picks = values.filter( row => row[0] !== "" ).flat();
        let results = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
        results.appendRow(picks);
        values.forEach( row => row[0] = "" );
        range.setValues(values);
        e.range.setValue(false);
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [onEdit Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [onEdit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Google Spreadsheet Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)
- [javascript Array Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)